# How to Assign selecteditem value for treeview

Tags: c#, wpf

How to add selecteditem value in below code. every time is geeting only null

```
 private void Button_Remove(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                string messageString = string.Empty;

                if (_treeView_Drugs.SelectedItem == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select an item to removcheck.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                    return;
                }
    }
```

Comment: check [TreeView.SelectedItem Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.selecteditem.aspx)

Comment: In Unit testing how can I check

Comment: How is your _treeView_Drugs bind with the UI tree view? By MVVM? With code behind?

Comment: TreeViewModel item = _treeView_Drugs.SelectedItem  as TreeViewModel; In Teeviewmodel some propertys are having